# Setting EventListener On Div Containing Image Not Triggering Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I have placed an image inside a div element and I'm setting a clicklistener on it, but the method `onGermanFlagClicked` does not execute.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" id="de">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png" heigth="50px" width="50px"/>
</div>

<script>
  var germanFlag = document.getElementById("de");
  germanFlag.addEventListener("onclick", onGermanFlagClicked);
  
  /* Changing language here */
  function onGermanFlagClicked(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
  }
</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Event is `"click"` not `"onclick"` so either `germanFlag.onclick = function(){}` or `germanFlag.addEventListener("click", onGermanFlagClicked);`

Comment: Was this only a typo in the question or did you just fix the problem in the question yourself?

Comment: @Andreas In the example it is working now but in my current code not - I'm trying to figure out which differences there are

Comment: Please add this info to the question. Right now you're asking about a problem which isn't present in the code...

Comment: **You corrected code based on comments. So, this issue can't be reproduced by future visitors. Rollbacked to Rev 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's: `germanFlag.addEventListener("click", onGermanFlagClicked);`
not `germanFlag.addEventListener("onclick", onGermanFlagClicked);`. Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

change `germanFlag.addEventListener("onclick", onGermanFlagClicked);` line to

```
germanFlag.addEventListener("click", onGermanFlagClicked);
```

> Note that you don't use the "on" prefix for the event; use "click" instead of "onclick".

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) is the list of all valid DOM events.

[Check here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) for more on JavaScript HTML DOM EventListener.